# threadin trouble!! - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run a file in python and inside of it is a class:

```
    class MyClass(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):  
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.varA = a
      self.varB = b
      self.varC = c
      self.varD = d
      print (self)
      self.run()
     def run(self):
      ...
```

in my file i create several threads, but i have this treaceback:
Exception in thread (nameThread):
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)

   TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not callable
```

this happends with all threads.
I'm confused

in MainThread I print after creation the state of every thread and first it's say 'started' but just after that it's say 'stopped'.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

sorry for misspelling
long time without write in english

here is the code that start the threads:

```
    for i in range(1,X):
     print ('inside' + str(i)) for debug
     nomb = 'thred' + str(i)
     t = threading.Thread(target=surtidor(i, fin, estado, s), name = 'THREAD' + str(i))
     hilos.append(t)
     t.start()
     print (hilos) # for debug
```

Hi again updating the situation:
Now I do what Tim Peters say, I call start() .- 
Now the threads really run but first they throw the same exception,  I know they run because they run a loop and in every repeat they print their names.
Any ideas why is that?

Comment: You should revise your question title to a more descriptive one. Your current title 'threadin trouble!! - Python' is really not helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emphasize what was already said in comments:  **DO NOT CALL .run()**.  As the docs say, `.start()`

> arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked
>   in a separate thread of control.

That's the only way `.run()` is intended to be used:  invoked *automatically* by - and only by - `.start()`.

That said, I'm afraid you haven't shown us the real cause of your trouble.  You need to show the code you use to create and to start the threads.  What you *have* shown cannot produce the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** call `run` in **init**

Here is what I would expect the normal use case of a threading class

```
import threading
class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):  
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.varA = a
      self.varB = b
      self.varC = c
      self.varD = d
      print (self)
      # self.run()
    def run(self):
        print self.varA


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MyClass('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    mc.start()
```

You should not leave out the code in `def run()`. It is hard to tell the exact cause of the problem

Comment: I'm sure that the code inside run() is not the problem, even if i put inside run() just a line like:

        print ("bye")

nothing change

Comment: you should not call `.run()` period. Use `.start()` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Agree. My bad